# Trying to add multiple grep commands within an exec

Tags: linux, grep, find, exec

I am trying to search all files in a directory (and all subdirectories) for a string. If the file has that string, I then want to search for the number of times another string occurs, in this case "snake" and output it. I would also like to output the lines on which "snake" occurs within the file.

```
echo "Files with Reptile:"
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -l "Reptile" {} \;
```

My challenge is how I add additional grep commands after the curly brackets. I have tried a couple of things and keep getting a "missing argument to -exec" error.

Am I trying to stuff too much into this find?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c "grep -l "Reptile" {} | xargs -I% grep -Hn snake %" \;
./rep1.txt:2:snake
./rep2.txt:5:another snake
```

Output contains colon-delimited lists in which the first argument is the file name (from the `-H` argument to `grep`), the second argument is the line number on which the desired term appears (from the `-n` argument to `grep`), and the third argument is the line itself.

The `xargs` can be moved outside the `find`, giving you:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -l "Reptile" {} \; | xargs -i grep -Hn snake {}
```

Note that the `-i` argument to `xargs` (which is equivalent to `-I{}` is deprecated but I use it often for convenience.

Input files:

```
$ tail -n+1 rep*.txt
==> rep1.txt <==
Reptile
snake
iguana
crocodile

==> rep2.txt <==
Reptile
alligator
turtle
another snake
komodo dragon

==> rep3.txt <==
Reptile
lizard
gecko
```

If you need to deal with malformed file names, you can think about incorporating `print0` and the `-0` option to xargs.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `-exec` predicates. Since `-exec` is only true if the command succeeds, you don't need to do anything special with the first `grep`.

```
find ... -exec grep -q "Reptile" {} \; -exec grep -Hn snake {} \;
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `-exec` predicates are conditionally dependent on preceding ones

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 't=$(mktemp)
        for fi
        do
                if grep -q Reptile "$fi"
                then
                        echo "$fi contains Reptile"
                        grep snake "$fi" | tee "$t"
                        echo "snake appeared on $(wc -l < "$t") line(s)"
                fi
        done
        rm -f "$t"
        ' sh {} +
```

This reports the names of files that contain the word/string “Reptile”,
even if they don’t contain the word “snake”,
and independently reports the number of lines that contain “snake”.

Oops; I misread the question, and thought that was a requirement. 
Taking it out is easy:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
        for fi
        do
                if grep -q Reptile "$fi"
                then
                        echo "$fi contains Reptile"
                        grep snake "$fi"
                fi
        done
        ' sh {} +
```

You can add a `-n` option to the `grep snake` if you want.

This should handle just about any valid filename. 
Check the other answer(s) with filenames beginning with space
and/or containing newline.